# How to do covariate analysis in LTA and calculate p-values?

Tags: regression, sas

I am facing an issue in SAS when trying to do regression modelling using Proc LTA. I want to estimate odds ratios for transitional probabilities of 8 covariates. Although my model converges SAS is dividing my covariates into half i.e. it provides me ORs for 4 covariates from time 1 to time 2 and for 4 other covariates for time 2 to time 3. I am not able to figure out why it does not provide 8 ORs for time 1 to time 2 and 8 ORs for time 2 to time 3. Can you please provide some guidance.